# Performing complicated calculation on bands in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, expression, band, calculate-values, vegetation-index

I'm trying to perform ANIR index calculation on my image collection. I'm having trouble writing the code in the right way. ANIR index formula is :

```
cos^-1[((a^2)+(b^2)+(c^2))/(2*a*b)]
```

(a2, b2 and c1, are Euclidean distances between bands B4, B8, B11/B12 respectively).

This is the function I have written so far-

```js
var addANIR = function(image) {
  var ANIR = image.expression(
  '(1/cosin)',
  {
    'B4': image.select('B4'),
    'B8': image.select('B8'),
    'B11': image.select('B11'),
    'A':((ee.Number(832.8-644.6).pow(2)).add(image.select('B8').subtract(image.select('B4')).pow(2))).sqrt(),
    'B':((ee.Number(1613.7-832.8).pow(2)).add(image.select('B11').subtract(image.select('B8')).pow(2))).sqrt(),
    'C':((ee.Number(1613.7-644.6).pow(2)).add(image.select('B11').subtract(image.select('B4')).pow(2))).sqrt(),
    'top':A.pow(2).add(B.pow(2)).add((C).pow(2))/ (ee.Number(2).multiply(A).multiply(B)),
    'cosin': top.cos()

  }).rename('ANIR');
  //NDVI index
  
  return image.addBands(ANIR.add(ee.Image(0.0)));
  //Add 0.0 value to NDVI (currently not in use)
  
 };
```

This function gives me an Error. What is wrong with the function/code?

Answer (score 3):

I've never calculated this index, and am not convinced I got it completely right. But based on what you provided, it could look something like this:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c94ed6bb713d414a265d4817244f287a

```
var addANIR = function(image) {
  var a = ee.Image().expression(
    'sqrt((832.8 - 644.6)**2 + (i.B8 - i.B4)**2)', {i: image}
  )
  var b = ee.Image().expression(
    'sqrt((1613.7 - 832.8)**2 + (i.B11 - i.B8)**2)', {i: image}
  )
  var c = ee.Image().expression(
    'sqrt((1613.7 - 644.6)**2 + (i.B11 - i.B4)**2)', {i: image}
  )
  var anir = ee.Image().expression(
    '1 / cos((a**2 + b**2 + c**2) / (2 * a * b))', {a: a, b: b, c: c}
  ).rename('ANIR')
  
  return image.addBands(anir)  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!

Comment: @user166621 consider accepting this answer if it solved your question